# Tapping in between a brake lever and an e-bike controller

Tags: microcontroller, switches, opto-isolator

I'm designing a piece of hardware that resides between an e-bike controller and the brake lever.
The difficulty is that the battery voltage is unknown and can be between 36-52v.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGNqNf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Question 1:

The blue and red line are the original brake wires. I'm creating a device that sits in between these wires.
For detecting the brake lever switch I decided to use the battery voltage as pull-up (just like the original controller box). I've used a 1M ohm bias resistor. This is enough to saturate the transistor as the collector-emitter current is very low. Again I don't exactly know the voltage before the bias resistor as the battery voltage can differ.

Using the 3.3v internal voltage as a pull-up is also an option and might be easier instead of using the battery voltage. However I still need some form of IO protection. The brake lever is open to the elements with a 1-2 meter cable. What is your opinion about that?

Question 2:

I also need to toggle the brake lever at the e bike controller box (faking it).
The circuit inside the e bike controller is unknown but I expect it to be something like the circuit I've drawn. I know they use a pull-up to battery voltage but it may also just be 3.3v/5v/12v/36v/42v/52v. Completely unknown. Also the current direction is unknown (I don't known which wire is red or blue in the example).

What would be the best way to toggle this? I don't want any mechanical devices like relais as the switch time will be in the 100ms. I now decided to use a AQH2223A which is a triac optocoupler. This feels like a bit overkill but I'm not 100% sure.